# Android sqlite database file location

Tags: android, sqlite

I am new to android. I tried to create a sqlite database using SqliteDbHelper class. What I want to know is the location, where the db file is located.

Comment: data->data->package->look for db etc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The database file will be located in /data/data/your package name/" and you can access this under the DDMS Perspective in eclipse.

Comment: Thanks!I found it there